# Need to install board and batten wood shutters to my brick house. What items do I need to do this how do I do it?

Tags: wood, shutters

I need to install wood board and batten shutters on my brick home and need to know what all I need to do it and how to do it. Thanks

Comment: you need the manufacturer's installation instructions

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9514/how-do-i-install-wood-shutters-on-a-brick-house?rq=1 seems like a very similar question. Can you examine it, and see if you still have questions?

Answer (score 1):

I used to work for www.timberlane.com  check out their hardware catalog for install ideas.  You might even be able to call and pick a salesperson's brain for install advice.  Especially if you need to buy hardware.  Brick can be tricky and I'm sure you don't want to do it twice.

And please don't down vote for suggesting experienced help.  There are a lot of questions like, "do you want to close your shutters" that make this a nuanced answer.  Even the offset of the trim around your window could change how it is installled.

Comment: Hahahah oops gotta edit that.